# Computing X^n With a Parallel Work-Optimal Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, parallel-processing

Given the following:

> Given X and N, where X, N are positive integers, and N is 2^K, design
>   a work-optimal PRAM algorithm to compute X^N.

How is it possible to parallelize an inherently sequential algorithm? Is this question prompt missing something?

With sequential algorithm:

```
# constraint, n is 2^k
power(x,n):
    k = log2(n)
    for i in range(1,k):
        x = x*x
    return x
```

Is it mathematically possible to parallelize this while  maintaining work-optimality. Time optimality is **not** necessary here.

Comment: You are not asked to parallelize an inherently sequential algorithm. You are asked to compute a mathematical function in a parallel manner. The function is not inherently sequential. You are not given an algorithm at all.

Comment: How is this function not inherently sequential?

Comment: Honestly, while I don't think the function is itself inherently sequential, I don't see a simple way to parallelize its computation. Trying to just have different processors handle different multiplications definitely isn't going to work; I think you'd have to stop treating multiplication as a fundamental operation, but optimal multiplication is still an active research problem, as far as I know. I think this problem might be missing something, or it might be a trick question.

Comment: Multiplication is associative, so you can do the usual tree-thing with log(n) parallel layers.

Comment: Unfortunately that will lead to an algorithm that is not work optimal, as you end up performing the same computation multiple times. For example, if you were to compute X^4, and broke it down to X^2 * X^2, and then placed each of those operations on their own threads, you would end up performing the same operation, X^2 in this case, unnecessarily multiple times.

Comment: @harold: Yeah, that was my first thought, but the tree branches are all redundant. You only need one of them.

Comment: Oh, right. Well there is nothing to do then, is there. It's already a work-optimal PRAM algorithm, it just happens to only use processor.. is that a cheat?